# Как при записи в файл пропускать дублирующее значение?

Tags: php

Подскажите как при записи в файл не допускать дублирующее значение 
есть файл

```
    1<|>Petro Boiko<|>bridun<|>
    2<|>Petro<|>petro<|>
    3<|>Petro<|>petro<|>


    $data = file("file.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

foreach($data as $rows)
    {
    $row = explode("<|>", $rows);   
    if (!strripos($rows, "<|>")) continue; 
    }

//////////////////////

if (is_writeable("file.txt"))
    {
    $f = fopen("file.txt", "a+");
    $write_text = "$max<|>$name<|>$mess<|>\n";  
    }
//////////////////////

    if (in_array($row[2], $rows))
        { //Если уже есть в массиве

        // удаляем строку

        echo ("Запись существует.");
        }
      else
        {
        fputs($f, $write_text);
        fclose($f);
        echo ("Запись добавлена.");
        }

          //else echo ("Не удалось записать в файл");
        }
    }
```